# Showing white screen after splash screen in window 7 phonegap

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I am developing apps for window phone 7 using phonegap. I am facing the problem when launching the apps in emulator. I can see the splashscreen but not the index page. I just see the white blank screen after splashscreen. While running on emulator I got message "this computer do not have required graphics processing unit configuration."

I test with other in built apps with visual studio for window phone. It work fine.

What is the problem? With my graphics or something else.

Comment: Possible causes for this issue include the following: Your computer does not meet hardware requirements for GPU emulation. Elements that require GPU emulation are not being cached. [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff637317(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: hey did you get any solution. bcoz I am facing same problem since 2 3 days.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set up your app to launch index.html. If you have change the tree it's not a problem. You can change it in CordovaLib, CordovaView.xaml, CordovaView.xaml.cs. In this one, you will find StartpageUri. Be sure that is pointing on your file

Comment: StartpageUri is pointing to my file.Here is code.  protected Uri _startPageUri = null;
        public Uri StartPageUri
        {
            get
            {
                if (_startPageUri == null)
                {
                    return new Uri(AppRoot + "www/index.html", UriKind.Relative);
                }
                else
                {
                    return _startPageUri;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                if (!this.IsBrowserInitialized)
                {
                    _startPageUri = value;}}}

Comment: I have tried different version of phonegap (1.7,2.4,2.7) but index.html page is never displayed on emulator but only see blank screen after splash screen gone.

Comment: did you try another emulator (i.e emulator 720p). And change the style of your index.html, in exemple make a red background color, to be sure to see your page when it's called.

Comment: I have tested on different emulator(7.8-512Mb, 7.8-256MB, 256MB and 512 Mb). When I change the background color I can see background color is changed. Also I have alert on body onload and deviceonready the alert message also donot popup. Also when browsing website from emulator , screen is blank.

Comment: If you try alert on Windows phone, alert don't work. You have to do navigator.notification.alert();

Comment: navigator.notification.alert(); show the alert message but I can't see index.html content on emulator.